# Vue.js Slows Down When Rendering Lots of Svg

Tags: vue.js, svg, vuex

I have a vue.js component called "Table".
Table renders approximately 25K "Cell" components, which are svgs, using a v-for.
Each cell component properly has a key identified.
The table renders fine, if a bit slowly.
The problem is that when I try to navigate away from that route, the browser seems to hang for about half a minute. It seems that it's taking a while to clear the dom. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide sample code and what you have tried to fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask